# placing ads on lists

Tags: android, xml, ads

I've created this XML file that brings up a list of different items, and I decided to add ads to this list,but the problem is that the ad covers the first item on the list and jumps to the second item directly.can anyone tell me how to override this problem?Another thing I'm looking for is to change the gravity of this list to be listed on the right instead of left.
Here's an image that illustrates my problems:
[image]

The XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:id="@+id/list_container"
  android:measureAllChildren="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >       
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_descption_label"
            android:gravity="right"
        />
        <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/list_descption_label"
            android:id="@+id/list_description"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_username_label"
            android:gravity="right"
        />
        <AutoCompleteTextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/list_username_label"
            android:id="@+id/list_username"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_password_label"
            android:gravity="right"
        />
        <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/list_password_label"
            android:id="@+id/list_password"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_email_label"
            android:gravity="left"
        />
        <AutoCompleteTextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/list_email_label"
            android:id="@+id/list_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_notes_label"
            android:gravity="right"
        />
        <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:minLines="5" 
            android:hint="@string/list_notes_label"
            android:id="@+id/list_notes"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a listview header.
Create an XML layout with your

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Inflate it and add it to the ListView.

```java
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                                         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View adView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myAdView, null, false);
yourListView.addHeaderView(adView);
```

For your second question, copy the android.R.... layout you are using from the SDK and change the gravity or customize your adaper.